# Communication between POX controller and Mininet Host

Tags: python, mininet, sdn, pox

Iam new in SDN world. Trying to send some data (load statistics) from a mininet host to the POX controller running. Socket Connection or wget from pox didn't work. Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: You are trying to measure bandwidth?

Comment: no..i am trying to run a loadbalancing algo based on the current cpu loads of the servers.

Comment: Try providing some code of what you have so far and you are trying to accomplish. Since there is no clear picture of what you are trying to do maybe check out this question at the mininet maillist
https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2013-December/003613.html